# Zend Db needs dateformat set for every insert query

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am trying to insert a couple of rows into an MSSQL server database via Zend\Db component. Some fields contain dates in german format, so DD.MM.YYYY but SQL Server expects YYYY-MM-DD. There is the SET DATEFORMAT DMY option which solves my problem via SQL Management Studio. However in PHP and using Zend\Db I have to put this statement in front of every INSERT statement. I do not know why? Isn't there an option to set this for a whole session?

Example:

```
// $this->db is an instance of \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
$this->db->query("SET LANGUAGE German;")->execute();
$this->db->query("SET DATEFORMAT dmy;")->execute();
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table}(";

...
$statement = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Result:

```
Statement could not be executed (22007 - 241 - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)
```

However, when I write:

```
$sql = "SET DATEFORMAT DMY; INSERT INTO {$table}(";
```

it works.

Any suggestions what is wrong or what I need to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using this method based on `dbAdapter->query()->execute()`, you are depriving yourself of the rich classes `Zend\Db\Sql`.
Through `Zend\Db\Sql\Insert`, simply extend this class as follows:

```
namespace MyProject\Db\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Insert as ZendInsert;
class Insert extends ZendInsert {
/**
 * @var array Specification array
 */
protected $specifications = [
    self::SPECIFICATION_INSERT => 'SET DATEFORMAT DMY; INSERT INTO %1$s (%2$s) VALUES (%3$s)',
    self::SPECIFICATION_SELECT => 'SET DATEFORMAT DMY; INSERT INTO %1$s %2$s %3$s',
];
}
```